# Simple Python script not moving objects away from center

Tags: python, scripting

**Warning**: I am a complete noob at Python Scripting :P

What I want to achieve is that all of the *selected objects* are moved away from the center randomly, so I have created a simple script that (should) do just that.

**Problem**: It is not moving moving parts around the scene.

```
import bpy
from random import randint

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    rand = (randint(0, 20) / 20) + 1
    obj.location.x = obj.location.x * rand
    obj.location.y = obj.location.y * rand
    obj.location.z = obj.location.z * rand
```

EDIT: Because the parts were centered at (0, 0, 0), they would not move at all; a.k.a. anything times 0 is 0!

Comment: please create an answer with your EDIT and set it as accepted, so the question will register as closed

Comment: If the initial position is `(0, 0, 0)` then multiplying by a random number wouldn't change the position. Try adding or setting the position with a random number.